# AlarmManager not firing alarm at specified time

Tags: android

I am using following code to put alarm on specific date and time.

```
mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(info.id, mCalendar);
```

and `ReminderManager.setReminder` function is:

```
public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) 
{       
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(DataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (mContext,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi); 
}
```

its not working properly, alarm goes off when I press the "Put Reminder" menu item in my app not the time I have specified.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the date is in the future?

I haven't checked that, but maybe this is the designed behavior if you try to set up an alarm in the past...

`2013-JAN-16 1:30` looks like past for me (at least in my timezone).

Comment: according to my time zone date is in future, But my emulator and system show 1 hour difference due to day light savings.

Comment: thanks for your help, setting correct time on emulator has solved my problem.